There is an error while updating the relation of a record in Prisma ORM
The User and Job models are as follows. They have a one-to-many relationship with each other:
(I only want to change a user's job. )
model User {
  id                String     @id @default(uuid())
  name              String     @db.VarChar(30)
  surname           String     @db.VarChar(30)
  email             String     @unique @db.VarChar(50)
  status            UserStatus @default(FREE)
  password          String
  birthday          DateTime
  gender            Gender
  photo             String?
  provinceId        String?
  province          Province?  @relation(fields: [provinceId], references: [id])
  districtId        String
  district          District   @relation(fields: [districtId], references: [id])
  job               Job        @relation(fields: [jobId], references: [id])
  jobId             String
  createdAt         DateTime   @default(now()) @map("created_at")
  updatedAt         DateTime   @updatedAt @map("updated_at")
  deleted           Boolean    @default(false)
}

model Job {
  id          String @id @default(uuid())
  key         String @db.VarChar(50)
  users       User[]
}

await Database.user.update({
        where: { id },
        data: {
            jobId: "135dff36-a1a2-4016-9e3b-5b99e148ceb3",
        },
        include: {
            job: true,
        },
    });

I only want to change the user's job, but I am getting the following error:
      Unknown argument `jobId`. Available options are marked with ?.
          at Tn (/Users/kyilmaz/Desktop/work-be/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:115:6855)
          at In.handleRequestError (/Users/kyilmaz/Desktop/work-be/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:122:6533)
          at In.handleAndLogRequestError (/Users/kyilmaz/Desktop/work-be/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:122:6211)
          at In.request (/Users/kyilmaz/Desktop/work-be/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:122:5919)
          at async l (/Users/kyilmaz/Desktop/work-be/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:127:11167)
          at Object.updateUser (/Users/kyilmaz/Desktop/work-be/src/domains/backoffice/users/service/index.ts:81:9)
          at Object.updateUser (/Users/kyilmaz/Desktop/work-be/src/domains/backoffice/users/controller/index.ts:61:3)
  "name": "PrismaClientValidationError",
  "clientVersion": "5.14.0

I only want to change the user's job
